# PHP, mysql_query just NOT working

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I'm ready to pull my hair out...

This works perfectly:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'prototype_wp_usr', 'password') or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('prototype_wp');
$query = "INSERT INTO wp_zsession_capture
        (id, session_id, user_login, first_name, last_name, user_email, phone_number, last_conviction)
        VALUES (
            'NULL', 
            '". session_id() ."',
            '". $_POST['user_login'] ."',
            '". $_POST['first_name'] ."',
            '". $_POST['last_name'] ."',
            '". $_POST['user_email'] ."',
            '". $_POST['phone_number'] ."',
            '". $_POST['last_conviction'] ."'
        )";

mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_close($link);
```

This does **NOT** work:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'prototype_wp_usr', 'password') or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('prototype_wp');
$query = "UPDATE wp_zsession_capture SET removed = 1 WHERE session_id = '$sessionid'";

mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_close($link);
```

These two pieces of code are within a form... if there are errors in the form, the FIRST sql query is run to save whatever is in the session at that point. If there are no errors, and after some other stuff goes on, the SECOND sql query is run to UPDATE the 'removed' status within those previously saved entries.

I have been tinkering with a million alternative syntaxes and I cannot get those rows to UPDATE. When I execute raw SQL within phpMyAdmin, it works fine. There is nothing logical about this... or maybe I'm just so fantastically tired.

FYI: $sessionid = session_id();

-- **UPDATE** --

I really do appreciate everyone's concern, but let me address some things:

1. Yes, there is a column in my table named 'removed' ... are you serious? :P
2. I am of course using session_start();
3. Yes, I am checking the $sessionid to make sure it is invoked. It's echoed on the page at all times and is also within any `die` statements I execute.
4. The FIRST query is responsible for creating the rows that the SECOND query is supposed to be updating... so the data is there.
5. `mysql_error()` does not produce anything ... there's simply no error.

Again, I appreciate your concern, but so far all suggestions have been tried and tried again.

[image]

Comment: did you check if $sessionid contains a valid id? if there is no error it probably means there was no matching row in the database. also: your first query does not do input validation... hello bobby tables.

Comment: Do you have a column 'removed' in that table?

Comment: Why people don't put mysql_error is beyond my understanding. And he uses it in connecting to host. 

Even worse books in php uses mysql_error in their examples.

P.s. Your code has sql injection vulnerability. Use PDO. Its not that difficult and will save you from many headaches later on.

Comment: @itachi, I appreciate your insight, but again... exhausted. And SQL injection is not an issue at this point.

Comment: Ok. But did you check the mysql error as suggested by all here? What is written there?

Comment: There is no error. Seriously.

Comment: @dcolumbus, I'm having the same problem, found a fix for this yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `mysql_error()` to obtain the error message from the database, like this:

```
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database: '.mysql_error());
```

The error could be one of many things, like for example maybe the user does not have the DELETE permission. If you don't use `mysql_error()` there's no way to know what happened.

**Edit** The data in your session_id column looks suspiciously short. Check how long the strings returned by `session_id` are and check the column length in the database. Inserting data that is too long for a column is not an error but it does crop the data.

Comment: Edited. Check the column definition

Comment: Ignore that. It's the right length...that preview isn't showing the entire string. Remember, I am able to UPDATE using SQL directly.

Comment: However, this does give me an idea... Are all session_id the same 32 md5 length?

Comment: The length depends on the `session.hash-bits-per-character` setting: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-bits-per-character

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried checking...

1. What the value of `$sessionid` is when the script is invoked
2. What error, if any, mysql returns?

You can do the latter by changing your `die()` to be...

```
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: +1 No idea why nobody ever looks at the error messages... :o)

Answer (score 0):

No idea why the second query does not execute. Without seeing your database table's schema and without you posting the contents of the server's generated error message, it really is going to be difficult to assist you. In the mean time though, I *highly* recommend you take a moment to do some research on the dangers of [SQL Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).

Might also want to ensure you call `session_start()` before messing with `session_id();`

Comment: I'm using `session_start()` ... and it's the FIRST query that does not execute properly.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason mysql_error() is returning blank is that more than one connection is open at the same time. I have had this issue recently while transferring scripts onto a newer server/version of PHP. Try providing the connection handle in your call like so: mysql_error( $link )

That should help you find what the error is, and knowing that will help us answer your question.

And, although you stated you weren't concerned about injection attacks - you should ALWAYS ESCAPE ALL DATA that comes from a user/questionable source. At least use mysql_real_escape_string() around EVERY $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_REQUEST, and $_SERVER variable you put into the database. I refer you to the story of little Bobby Tables...

[image: This is what happens if you don't escape user input.]

( http://xkcd.com/327/ )

Answer (score -1):

Uncheck your Auto increament box into the database structure then check it again to save auto increament structure, your problem will be solved. I got this kind of error while doing

> mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

Error Was

> database update failed: auto increatment failed to updated by Engine.

Seems like this error was occur i omitted to copy

Comment: This post is 4 years old. Why are you providing answers in such an old post?